# Unable to login with user created by manager FireBase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I created a small firebase admin that creates users through python. The problem is that I am not able to connect using the users that I have created.My login is based on e-mail/password.

My Python:

```
def createUserAccount(_uid,_email,_number,city,firstName,lastName,password,street,isManager):
    user = auth.create_user(
          uid= _uid,email=_email)
    print 'Sucessfully created new user: {0}'.format(user.uid)
    refAccount.child(user.uid).set({
        'City': city,
        'Email': _email,
        'FirstName': firstName,
        'LastName': lastName,
        'Password': password,
        'PhoneNumber': _number,
        'Street': street,
        'isManager': isManager
    }
)


createUserAccount('tomer','p@g.com','0545286111','p','tomer','zaks','123456','t','False')
```

Here might be a clue:
[image: auth]
All users created by the manager does not have an e-mail image under the providers, while the users created through the actual app have an e-mail image.

Sorry if this is a newbie question, I am new to firebase, and was unable to find info via google. Help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, the answer was quite simple even though I searched for it for a while.

The login is configured by email/password and when creating a new user I only entered an uid and an e-mail with no password.

now my fixed code is:

```
def createUserAccount(_uid,_email,_number,city,firstName,lastName,password,street,isManager):
    user = auth.create_user(
          email=_email,****password=password****)
    print 'Sucessfully created new user: {0}'.format(user.uid)
    refAccount.child(user.uid).set({
        'City': city,
        'Email': _email,
        'FirstName': firstName,
        'LastName': lastName,
        'Password': password,
        'PhoneNumber': _number,
        'Street': street,
        'isManager': isManager
    }
)
```